# Multiple positional operators in Positional Projection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch data by querying something like this here, but seems like mongodb does not allow two positional projection at same time. I tried to google it on the internet but can't find a solution.

```
MyModel.find({}, { 
   "_id": 0,
   "emailAddress": 1,
   "alib.elements.$.questions.$.values": 1
})
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Here's the error in case if it helps.

> MongoError: Positional projection 'alib.elements.$.questions.$.values' contains the positional operator more than once.

Expected Output:

```
{
 alib: {
   elements: [
         {
             questions: [
               {
                 values: ....
               }
             ]
          }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you show your data model and expected query result?

Comment: @mickl I've made an edit. Ps can't really show the model as its completely dynamic. I hope the desired output structure might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations):

> Only one positional $ operator may appear in the projection document.

You can use double [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator instead:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "alib.elements": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$alib.elements",
                    in: {
                        questions: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$$this.questions",
                                in: { values: "$$this.values" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iwF21Lnkb-E)

Comment: can you tell me how can I ignore some values inside $map for example if value==2 I dont want this question in array.

Comment: @AliHussam you need additional operator `$filter`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/ please try by yourself and if you need some help then you can open another question